# CasperJS - How to save some data for each page from an array?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to crawl a website using CasperJS but I ran into a problem.

One the first page I collect the links I want to crawl and save them to an array using the `getLinks()` function - this works well.

Then I want to crawl each page from this array (I got this part working) and I want to grab some details from each of these pages.

My code as follows (trimmed the working stuff like casper start and login etc.):

```
// Casper start here, and some login stuff, all these are working fine so I removed them to have a light example

// ....
// ....
// ....

// Function for saving members to an array
function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll(".member_name_and_title");
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(link) {
        return link.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].href
    });
}

casper.then(function() {
    // Aggregate results 
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);

    casper.each(links, function (self, link) {
        self.thenOpen(link, function () {

            var details = this.evaluate(function(){
                document.getElementsByClassName('member_name')[0].textContent;
            });

            // Grab details for each member
            var data = details + " - " + link;

            // Save data
            var fs = require('fs');
            fs.write('results/output.txt', JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '), 'aw');

        });
    });

});

// Casper run
casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

The problem is that the `details` var will return null, so the final `output.txt` would be something like:

```
"null - domain.com/link1"
"null - domain.com/link2"
"null - domain.com/link3"
"null - domain.com/link4"
"null - domain.com/link5"
```

The `link` var is working fine but the `details` var is returning null.

When I go to any of the urls from the array (example: domain.com/link1) and run `document.getElementsByClassName('member_name')[0].textContent` in the browser console it returns the value correctly so I'm sure the targeting is fine.

I'm not sure what I'm missing or what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Beside the forgotten `return`, have you checked that the page that is delivered to CasperJS actually contains the element that you're trying to scrape (screenshot or page source)? If not, have you tried to wait for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured this out in the end, totally rookie mistake ... The query was correct the problem was caused by the page load, or better to say the links from the array were not loaded before the actual query was ran.

To test this I used [captureSelection()](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#captureselector) inside the `self.thenOpen` function to capture the state of the page when it's open, but right before the data is collected.

```
this.captureSelector('1.jpg', '#page');
```

I immediately noticed that the page was not fully loaded, hence the `return document.querySelector('.member_name.').textContent;` returning `null`.

To fix this I've added a 1.5s wait time, as follows:

```
casper.wait(1500, function() {
  var details = this.evaluate(function(){
    return document.querySelector('.member_name').textContent;
  });
});
```

Rookie mistake but might help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a return as mentioned below:

```
var details = this.evaluate(function(){
    return document.getElementsByClassName('member_name')[0].textContent;
});
```

**EDIT:**

This worked for me. My code setup is as follows:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

function getLinks() {
    var matchedLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".member_name_and_title");
    return Array.prototype.map.call(matchedLinks, function(link) {
        return link.href;
    });
}

casper.start('http://localhost:8080');

casper.then(function() {
    // Aggregate results 
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);

    casper.each(links, function (self, link) {

        // INSPECT: Check if it shows the correct link here.
        self.echo('Opening link:' + link);

        self.thenOpen(link, function () {

            var details = this.evaluate(function(){
                // INSPECT: Make sure to 'return' the text content.
                return document.getElementsByClassName('member_name')[0].textContent;
            });

            // Grab details for each member
            var data = details + " - " + link;

            // INSPECT: Check if the data is correct.
            self.echo(data);

            // Save data
            var fs = require('fs');
            fs.write('results/output.txt', JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '), 'aw');
        });
    });
});


casper.run(function(){
    this.exit();
});
```

My html files are as below:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello CasperJs</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="page1.html" class="member_name_and_title">Page 1</a>
<a href="page2.html" class="member_name_and_title">Page 2</a>
<a href="page3.html" class="member_name_and_title">Page 3</a>
<a href="page4.html" class="member_name_and_title">Page 4</a>

</body>
</html>
```

page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page 1 Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<p class="member_name">Page 1 Text</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Similar HTML markup for page2.html, page3.html and page4.html. My http server was running at port 8080.

My console output is as follows:

```
Opening link:http://localhost:8080/page1.html
Opening link:http://localhost:8080/page2.html
Opening link:http://localhost:8080/page3.html
Opening link:http://localhost:8080/page4.html
Page 1 Text - http://localhost:8080/page1.html
Page 2 Text - http://localhost:8080/page2.html
Page 3 Text - http://localhost:8080/page3.html
Page 4 Text - http://localhost:8080/page4.html
```

I am using casperjs 1.1.3 with phantomjs 2.1.1.

Can you update your code and share your console output and package versions?

Comment: I just tried but it's the same unfortunately, `details` var is still null.

Comment: What is the output if you modify as below:
`var details = this.evaluate(function(){
  var content = document.getElementsByClassName('member_name')[0].textContent;
  this.echo(content);
  return content;
 });`

Comment: Same... null as output. I've also tried to wrap the whole thing in a `casper.then` function after the `.each`, but once again it returns null.  Furthermore I've tried to console.log at every step to see if its something in-between messing up things but from the start to the end it's always null. I just double check again the targeting via browser console call and there it's returning the value correctly.